# System Hangs at call sem_post()

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, semaphore

I'm observing pretty strange problem when my application sometimes hangs for approximately 900us when trying to increment semaphore with `sem_post()`.

I identified it through the following code, which measure how long it take to increment the semaphore.

```
uint64_t tsc = rte_get_tsc_cycles();
sem_post(&m_a);
tsc = rte_get_tsc_cycles() - tsc;
if (tsc >= rte_get_tsc_hz() / 8192) // 122us, fast division
{
    printf("** sem_post %luus sem=%d **\n", (1000000 * tsc) / rte_get_tsc_hz(), SemVal());
}
```

How can I tackle such issue? thanks.

Comment: What other threads are doing?

Comment: Please show a [mre]. 0.9ms is not a _very_ long time.

Comment: Other threads that using the semaphore (calling sem_wait()) have a dedicated core which used only by them.

The thread that incrementing the semaphore running on a separate core together with another system task.

Comment: Is this linux or QNX?

Comment: linux - ubuntu OS

Comment: For Linux, use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,...)`

Comment: How do you know this is an issue that needs to be solved?  If you didn't have that timing code, would you even know about any potential problem?  And how do you know that the timing reported is accurate? Or that the hanging isn't in `rte_get_tsc_hz()`, for example?